# grub insmod error incompatible license

Tags: licensing, grub

I am using grub 2.02.  When I attempt to load a module (for testing purposes), the loader fails, with an error " incompatible license".  This is one of those obscure problems which seems to be related to version control issues.  I haver tried the following licenses, and have also tried using no license.

```
MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPLv2+");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPLv3+");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPLv3");
```

Can anyone tell me what is the magic word to get rid of this error message?

Answer (score 0):

The macro is called GRUB_MOD_LICENSE, not MODULE_LICENSE.

Additionally, the licenses considered valid are (as extracted from [grub-core/kernel/dl.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grub.git/tree/grub-core/kern/dl.c?id=ff84a9b868ea36da23248da780b8e85bdc4c183d#n448)):

- GPLv3
- GPLv3+
- GPLv2+

By the way - GRUB 2.02 is not released: the latest tag available is `grub-2.02-beta2`